# What is the origin of the Persian word شكر meaning Sugar?

Tags: etymology, persian

Google says the word Sugar originates from سكر in Arabic. Yet the classic dictionary القاموس المحيط says the word comes from شكر in Persian. Any help with the etymology of the Persian word شكر?

Answer (score 7):

The word for “sugar” in virtually all languages goes back to Sanskrit śárkarā. From Sanskrit it developed into North-West Prakrit śakara, which was borrowed into Middle Persian as šakar, and then from Persian into Arabic as sukkar. The words in European languages all derive directly or indirectly from Arabic.